# How to add words to dictionary for future spell check?

Tags: ipad, spellcheck

On my PC and MacBook Air I have the option to right click on a word underlined in red to “Add to Dictionary” and I’m wondering if I can do the same on my iPad Pro. Is this possible or do I simply have to live with it or disable spell checking? Thanks.

Comment: In Settings > General > Keyboard you can edit text replacement to add the corrected versions of misspelled words. And I saw something the other day  that I think was half joking where the user added some of their commonly used swear words as the names on a contact. Looked... ummm... amusing, but just might work.

Comment: Sounds like quite a bit of work. I thought that it'd be as simple as having an "Add to Dictionary" option but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

When **Pages, Numbers or Keynote** detects a word that it doesn't recognise, it will **underline the word** with a **dotted red line.**

- On iPad or iPhone, tap the underlined word, then tap Learn Spelling (you may need to tap Replace first).

[image: Image showing 'learn spelling option']

**If you want to define the word then:**

- Select the word then tap on 'define' and add definition there

[image: Image showing 'define option']